# regex middle name initial with or without it there

Tags: regex

I seem not to get it right to validate a user FirstName + LastName and checking for MiddleName like this:

```
John Doe - Valid
John M Doe - Valid
John Mr Doe - Invalid
John m Doe - Invalid
```

So, MiddleName can only be an uppercase letter.

What I came up with:

- FirstName + LastName should have at least 3 chars - OK
- Should be always FirstName and a LastName - OK

Cannot figure out how to check for MiddleName to have only 1 char if is present.

My current regex is like this:

```
var isValid = /^((\b[a-zA-Z]{3,40}\b)\s*){2,}$/.test($(this).val());
// ^((\b[a-zA-Z]{3,40}\b)\s*){2,}$ - actual regex
```

Comment: Can you please clarify if the max chars First and Last Name can have is 40? Is there any max char limit for them? I mean, if there can be any number of chars in First and Last names, why use `40` in the limiting quantifiers?

Answer (score 4):

You may use

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{3,40}(?:\s[A-Z])?\s[a-zA-Z]{3,40}$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NeIl6T/3). **NOTE**: `{3,40}` is a [**limiting quantifier**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) that matches 3 to 40 consecutive occurrences of the quantified subpattern (that is, `[a-zA-Z]` letter pattern here. If you do not intend to limit the upper bound (the max letter limit) for the First and Last Names, just remove `40`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]{3,40}` - 3 to 40 ASCII letters
- `(?:\s[A-Z])?` - (**here**) an optional sequence of

  - `\s` - a whitespace
  - `[A-Z]` - a single *uppercase* ASCII letter
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `[a-zA-Z]{3,40}` - 3 to 40 ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = [' John Doe', 'John M Doe', 'John Mr Doe', 'John m Doe'];
var rx = /^[a-zA-Z]{3,40}(?:\s[A-Z])?\s[a-zA-Z]{3,40}$/;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```

Comment: Can i enforce that char (middlename) to be capital letter ?

Comment: @Wiktor You can use `{3,}` for 3 or more characters, without limiting it to 40.

Comment: That is taken from the original regex. If there is no upper bound, then sure, `{3,}` should be used to match 3 *or more* consecutive occurrences of the quantified subpattern. OP frequently do not write in words the exact requirements, but their attempts speak more than the words.

Comment: @123onetwothree I updated your question to include this last-minute requirement.

Comment: is the non-capture pattern (?:) necessary here or is it just a good practice to add it

Comment: @ThirumalaiParthasarathi A [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon) in such a small pattern is not giving any significant boost, it is just a best practice to use capturing groups only when you need to access the captured substrings later. Here, it is validation OP cares about, so there is no point *capturing* any part of the match. Some would use a capturing group here for readability reasons, however, I do not see any problem with the `(?:...)` readability.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
/^[A-Za-z]{3,}\s+([A-Z]\s+)?[A-Za-z]{3,}$/
```

[Check here](https://regex101.com/r/gc5efi/2) for a demo.

---

Explanation of how it works:

- `^` start of string.
- `[A-Za-z]{3,}` checks for 3 or more letters.
- `\s+` checks for one or more whitespace characters.
- `([A-Z]\s+)?` checks for one capital letter character followed by one or more whitepscae characters, optionally. So it either matches a single letter + spaces, or nothing.
- `[A-Za-z]{3,}` checks for 3 or more letters, again.
- `$` end of string.

Comment: you example allows Jo3n Doe

Comment: More, it also matches [`____ ____`](https://regex101.com/r/gc5efi/3). It is more appropriate to name `\w` a *word* char since it matches alphanumeric *and* `_` chars.

Comment: Updated for stricter matching.